# Fortran procedure pointer points to a subroutine that does nothing

Tags: pointers, fortran, procedure

I have a code like this

```
:
procedure(),pointer :: p
if ()
  p => job1
else
  p => job2
endif

do i=1,a_big_number
  call x(...)
  call p(i,j,k)
enddo
```

The subroutine 'job1' does some work, but the subroutine 'job2' does nothing. In other words, under some circumstances, I need to finish 'x' and 'job1'. Under other circumstances, I only need to do 'x'. My question is how should I define job2. It seems simply using null() does not work. What I am doing right now is like:

```
subroutine job2(i,j,k)
integer,intent(in) :: i,j,k
end subroutine
```

However, this looks silly, and I got a lot compiling warning when I compiled the code because those arguments were not used. Is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could nullify the procedure pointer in the case that there was nothing useful to do, and then test the association status prior to invoking the procedure through the pointer.

```
PROCEDURE(interface_that_matches_job1), POINTER :: p
IF (...) THEN
  p => job1
ELSE
  NULLIFY(p)   ! Or p => NULL()
END IF

DO i = 1, a_big_number
  CALL x(...)
  IF (ASSOCIATED(p)) CALL p(i,j,k)
END DO
```

Comment: The reason I want to do this is that I can avoid a conditional judgement in the do loop. If I do it in your way, it will be the same as putting if(...) call job1 in the do loop. Then I won't need a procedure pointer here. Sorry that I did not make my point clear.

Comment: If you could just do `call p(...)` and have compiler automatically decide to call the procedure pointer `p` if it pointed to something or to decide not call anything if the pointer is null, then the compiler would be doing an IF behind the scenes, as it were.  With your concern for run-time speed, what difference does it make if the compiler automatically tests whether the procedure pointer is null or if you have to write out the `if (associated(p))` test?

Comment: Further to what M.S.B. says, if execution speed is motivating your requirements then I'd expect the overhead of the dynamic call of the procedure pointed at by the pointer to be greater than a simple conditional test anyway (i.e. calling a procedure that does nothing takes longer than testing a logical and not calling a procedure).  Execution wise, both options are more than likely irrelevant anyway in the context of a real program.  If you requirements are motivated by some other situation, then it would help to know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is really about the `if` statement in the loop, you could just put the `if` statement outside of the loop:

```
if (condition) then
  do ii = 1, big_number
    call x(...)
    call p(i,j,k)
  end do
else
  do ii = 1, big_number
    call x(...)
  end do
end if
```

Then do some timings on this version and then on a version with the `if` inside the loop:

```
do ii = 1, big_number
  call x(...)
  if (condition) then
    call p(i,j,k)
  end if
end do
```

I'd rather guess that you won't see any significant difference between them, as the subroutine call in the loop may already giving you an overhead much larger as the one caused by the `if` statement.